# Is there a way to convert this "for i" c++ preprocessor macro to modern C++ (11+)?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to replace this C++ preprocessor macro with something more modern.

```
#define fori(FORI_TYPE, FORI_FROM, FORI_TO) \
            for(FORI_TYPE i{FORI_FROM}; \
            ((FORI_FROM) < (FORI_TO)) ? (i < (FORI_TO)) : (i > (FORI_TO)); \
            ((FORI_FROM) < (FORI_TO)) ? ++i : --i )
```

Ideally, I would be able to get rid of all the ? operators (can constexpr be useful here?) and have "fori" not incur any overhead cost like it does now with the proceprocessor version (evaluations of ? operators). Also, type safety.

Usage example:

```
fori(size_t, 0, n)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to iterate over all numbers in range, or you intend to use `i` as an index into container (i.e. you want to iterate over items)?

Comment: The macro is used in a wide variety of contexts, it can be used as an index or in calculations, whatever. This is for multi-project-wide usage.

Comment: The problem is that you need to replace this in an already existing project? If so, can't you write a routine that actually reads in the source of the project and changes it somewhat like the pre-processor would?

Comment: @Aziuth Changes it to _what_, I think is the point

Comment: Just a personal advice: DON'T. Just don't. Macros are bad because they are hard to write, read and debug, but if they meet your needs, just use them. Modern C++ meta programming is certainly a bit nicer than old C preprocessor macros, but the code is not really easier to understand or debug... If you want to change something, educate programmers to use the language. Using meta-programming to only save few characters is, er... something I do not like.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not really understand why not to use an old-fashioned `for(size_t i =...)` instead.  Little bit more code and one must differentiate between incrementing and decrementing, but it works without any tricks. Or other typical ways to use `for`, iterators or for-each. Looks to me like the solution of something that isn't a problem, and I'm trying to understand why he needs the macro in the first place.

Comment: You could consider using `iota_view` from [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) which is being added to C++20

Comment: @Aziuth I largely agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, you're *always* going to need to know which direction to iterate, so you can't get rid of that overhead. That said, by switching away from macros, you can at least make it easier to optimise (partially by making the inputs `const` to promote folding of duplicate/similar conditions on them, and partially by precalculating a "step" distance to eliminate some of those conditions entirely).

As far as macros go, that one isn't too bad (though it could probably use a `()` or two…).

The truly "modern" thing to do would be to use a [counting iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), or [something related to `irange`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52217/2503).

For example, naively adapting Neil's code to provide automatic step direction detection:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class range
{
private:
    class iter
    {
    private:
        T at, step;
    public:
        iter(T at, T step) : at(at), step(step) {}
        bool operator!=(iter const& other) const { return at != other.at; }
        T const& operator*() const { return at; }
        iter& operator++() { at += step; return *this; }
    };

    T begin_val;
    T end_val;
    T step_val;

public:

    range(const T begin_val, const T end_val)
        : begin_val(begin_val)
        , end_val(end_val)
        , step_val(begin_val > end_val ? -1 : 1)
    {}

    iter begin() { return iter(begin_val, step_val); }
    iter end() { return iter(end_val, step_val); }
};

int main()
{
   for (auto i : range<unsigned>(42, 10))
      std::cout << i << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}

// Output: 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/790b35335b35b4e3))

Or, to be quite frank, you could just write the following and be done with it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   for (unsigned int i = 42; i > 10; --i)
      std::cout << i << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}

// Output: 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fd78ad6b8e3b9e0))

Everybody's going to understand that; no tricks required.

In either case, and despite my examples above, [I'd actually advise *not* using unsigned types for this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/11/the-perils-of-unsigned-iteration-in-cc).

Comment: *you're always going to need to know which direction to iterate, so you can't get rid of that overhead* - If all the bounds are given at compile time, there's really no reason why an implementation could not just adjust the iterator accordingly without a branch. You will need the branch at compile time, but there is really no reason to carry it over into the generated runtime code.

Comment: @ComicSansMS With "`n`" I assume they're not known at compile time, but otherwise you'd be right of course.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

We can get rid of the macro by using a template though it does mean having to add a callback function.

```
//f is of the form void func(int i)
template <typename T, typename F>
void fori(const T from, const T to, F f)
{
    for(
        T i  = from;
        (from < to) ? (i < to) : (i > to);
        (form < to) ? ++i : --i 
    ) {
         f(i);
 }
```

usage:

```
fori<int>(1, 20, [](int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
});
```

This also can probably be improved using C++20 concepts.

Comment: You can remove the first  `? :` too, just replace it with `from != to`.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a sequence of a type, we’d want to use a generator. Range for will use it’s output:

```
for(auto i: range<size_t>(0, n)) {
  std::cout << n << " ";
}
```

And:

```
template <typename T> class range {
  T a, b;
public:
  typename wrap<T> begin() const { return a; }
  typename wrap<T> end() const { return b; }
};
```

The wrapper would imbue the value with some properties (types and methods) that an iterator should carry, but is rather simple for numeric types.